# Voiceover (iOS) not reading page titles

Tags: accessibility, mobile-safari, voiceover

I'm testing a specific web site for work, in Safari on iOS 11.4.1, with VoiceOver turned on. VoiceOver is not reading page titles -- What are the possible causes of this? Please let me know if you have questions for clarification; there are several pages in a user workflow, so the code is different for each.

Note: This functionality works with a desktop screenreader, NVDA.

Comment: Hmm, I'm hearing this behavior too (11.4.1).  I don't have a device with an older version so can't test if it's a regression but I'm pretty sure the title used to be read.  If I follow a link, the new page that's loaded does not say the page title.  If I navigate to the "tabs button" (bottom right icon) and double tap to display the list of open pages, I can navigate through the list and hear the page titles.

Comment: It appears this is a (usability) issue with the latest version of iOS. Leaving the question open, in case people have workarounds, or other clarification.